# Simple Java Program has problem with if / else

Tags: java

I'm quite new to programming, and I've made a program with toy cars rental. There is only one issue, if I input 11 and 16, the program works fine. But if I input 2 and 4 (for example). The program won't show anything after `System.out.println("Total time " + (end - beginning));`

The price point from 0 to 7 and from 17 to 24 is 1$.
From 7 to 17 its 2$.

Please help! Most likely, I have messed up with the notation. Please show how to write properly the code. Thank you in advance!

PS. I can only modify information in the after "Complete from here". And I can't use arrays, loops, etc. Only basic stuff (if / else, <=, !=, int, double, boolean, etc.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Car {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Give an Int as a starting hour : ");
    int beginning = clavier.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Give an Int as an ending time : ");
    int end = clavier.nextInt();

    /*******************************************
     * Complete from here.
     *******************************************/

    int tarif1 = 0;
    int tarif2 = 0;
    int tarif3 = 0;
    int total = tarif1 + tarif3 + (tarif2 * 2); 
    if (((beginning < 0) || (beginning >= 24)) || ((end <= 0) || (end > 24))) {                       
    System.out.println("Time must be within 0 and 24 !");
    } else {
        if ((beginning - end) <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Not enough time !");
    } else {
        if ( beginning > end) {
    System.out.println("Error, beginning > end");
        } else {
            if (beginning > 0) {
                System.out.println("Total time " + (end - beginning));
                if (beginning < 7) {
                    tarif1 = (7 - beginning);                   
                } else {
                    tarif1 = 0; {
                if ((24 - end) <= 7) {
                    tarif3 = (end - 17);
                } else {
                    tarif3 = 0; {
                }
                tarif2 = ((end - beginning) - tarif1 - tarif3);
                System.out.println((tarif1 + tarif3) + " hours in 1 dollar tariff");
                System.out.println(tarif2 + " hours in 2 dollar tariff");
                total = tarif1 + tarif3 + (tarif2 * 2);


    System.out.print("Amount to pay is : " + total);
    System.out.println(" dollar(s).");
            }






    /*******************************************
     * No modifications after this line.
     *******************************************/

    clavier.close();
   }

    }
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: can you fix the indentation of the code please

Comment: You should include the stack trace

Comment: @AkashRajput I'm sorry, I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: I strongly suspect you're missing a `}` after the line `tarif1 = 0;`. If you're using an IDE, get it to reformat your code - it will make issues like this more apparent.

Comment: @dangee1705 How can you do it? What I am supposed to do?

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle still didn't work out. But thanks!

Comment: make sure each opening bracket has a closing bracket, and each line under a bracket needs to be indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code piece

```
if (beginning < 7) {
    tarif1 = (7 - beginning);                   
} else {
```

the closing bracket of else part spans across all code with `println`, thus it is not printing. The program simply can't reach it. You should put the closing bracket earlier. I don't know your exact intention but try this:

```
if (beginning < 7) {
    tarif1 = (7 - beginning);                   
} else {
    tarif1 = 0; 
}
if ((24 - end) <= 7) {
    tarif3 = (end - 17);
} else {
    tarif3 = 0; 
}
```

And you should remove that extra curly brace further down the code.

Consider using *else if* structure and work on proper indentation as it will make your code more readable and less error prone in the future.